# PHP Symfony - disable google fonts on youtube videos

Tags: php, symfony, youtube, google-font-api, google-fonts

On my website i have embedded Youtube video which somehow loads google fonts with himself. Is there any way that I can disable it, because i have google compaint on that?

code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="youtubelink" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If I remove code, google font will stop appears, but if i use it in this way then google fonts are present

I tried to google the issue, however i found only some solution related for wordpres. Im using Symfony PHP framework

Comment: No, you can not disable that - you don't have any influence over what happens inside this iframe, since its content is loaded from a different domain.

Comment: BTW: this problem has nothing to do with Symfony nor with PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly

This is only possible if the page, or in this case video is on the same domain as your page.

If you was making an iframe of content on your own domain you would be able to stylise that page at its source but when embedding a video the style of the source is what the client browser will load

Comment: Bad/unclear english language. Answer could be simpler/clearer